# Bison C to Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, for-loop, bison

I need to translate a for loop from C to Matlab.
I have the following grammar:

```
stmt            : stmt_while
                | stmt_for
                |...
                ;

stmt_for        : FOR '(' for_exp ')' stmt  {  }
                    ;

for_exp         : exp ';' exp ';' exp   {  }
                | exp ';' exp ';'       {  }
                | exp ';'     ';' exp   {  }
                | exp ';'     ';'       {  }
                |     ';' exp ';' exp   {  }
                |     ';' exp ';'       {  }
                |     ';'     ';' exp   {  }
                |     ';'     ';'       {  }
                ;
```

The for loops in Matlab have a completely different syntax so I do not know how to implement the translation.
The simplest solution seems to me to translate it in a while:

```
                                      exp1;
for(exp1; exp2; exp3){                while(exp2){
   for_body...             ==>           for_body...
}                                        exp3;
                                      }
```

You have other solutions?
Thank you all.

Comment: It really depends on what `exp2` and `exp3` are.

Comment: To clarify, if you want a general solution that will work regardless of what `exp2` and `exp3` are then the `while` loop is the only option. But if you have a specific `for` loop that you'd like to replace, there is likely a way to do it using MATLAB's `for` loop. If you can provide us with more information about your specific loop we can provide more help.

Comment: I should translate a for generic cycle from C to matlab without know if the statement is in the most common form, for example for (i = 0; i <n; i ++) ...

Comment: I fail to see the C syntax on your first code. Is that C?.....

Comment: Yes. Do you think there is some mistake?